# Suggestions For Multiple Sub-String Filter With Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, multiple-columns

```
My Dataframe:
```

[image]

or:

```
   Symbol List   mic reuters_exchange_code
12     1COV.DE  XETR                   .DE
13      2GB.DE  XETR                   .DE
14     2HRA.DE  XETR                   .DE
32       3IN.L  XLON                    .L
64       888.L  XLON                    .L
66      93M.DE  XETR                   .DE
70     A1OS.DE  XETR                   .DE
71      A2A.MI  MTAA                   .MI
72      A3M.MC  XMAD                   .MC
73      A4Y.DE  XETR                   .DE
74       A5G.I  XDUB                    .I
76      AAB.CO  XCSE                   .CO
77      AAD.DE  XETR                   .DE
78      AAG.DE  XETR                   .DE
80      AAK.ST  XSTO                   .ST
81     AALB.AS  XAMS                   .AS
82       AAL.L  XLON                    .L
83       AAM.S  XSWX                    .S
84      AAQ.DE  XETR                   .DE
86       AAS.L  XLON                    .L
87        AA.L  XLON                    .L
88      ABBN.S  XVTX                    .S
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

In column 1 first filter out '**XSWX**' and '**XVTX**' to get '**SW**' and '**VX**' respectively.

...then in column 2 replace only the '**.S**' strings with '**SW**' and '**VX**'

...to get a result showing '**AAM.SW**' and '**ABBN.VX**' instead its current '**AAM.S**' and '**AABN.S**' in the index column.

Comment: I see you have your dataframe in `jupyter notebook`, but we cannot copy a screenshot. Please `print()` the dataframe and paste it here so we can run the code ourselves.

Comment: Ok happy to but how do I do that? sorry Ive never been asked this before.

Comment: `print(dataframe.reset_index())`. I use `reset_index()` because I see this is see that `symbol list` is your index in this case, and this is hard to copy for us.

Comment: done print(dataframe.reset_index()) ...do I then save into html and attach that file here?

Comment: Just copy the ouput of jupyter notebook and paste it in your post. Its that simple.

Comment: done...did it...hope it helps =D

Comment: Can you do `print(df[['Symbol List', 'mic', 'reuters_exchange_code']])` since this is still not copyable.

Comment: yup...worked. Added the data as requested. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) since you have more than one condition. So we can fix our `reuters_exchange_code` column. After that we fill `Symbol List` by concatting `bats_name` with `reuters_exchange_code` like following:

```
conditions = [
    (df['mic'] == 'XSWX'),
    (df['mic'] == 'XVTX')
]

choices = ['.SW','.VX']

df['reuters_exchange_code'] = np.select(conditions, 
                                        choices, 
                                        default=df['reuters_exchange_code'])

df['Symbol List'] = df['bats_name'] + df['reuters_exchange_code']

print(df)
   Symbol List bats_name                                  company_name   mic  \
0      1COV.DE      1COV                                   Covestro AG  XETR   
1       2GB.DE       2GB                                   G Energy AG  XETR   
2      2HRA.DE      2HRA                            H&R GmbH & Co KGaA  XETR   
3        3IN.L       3IN                         3i Infrastructure PLC  XLON   
4        888.L       888                              888 Holdings PLC  XLON   
5       93M.DE       93M                            MPH Health Care AG  XETR   
6      A1OS.DE      A1OS                          All for One Steeb AG  XETR   
7       A2A.MI       A2A                                       A2A SpA  MTAA   
8       A3M.MC       A3M  Atresmedia Corp de Medios de Comunicacion SA  XMAD   
9       A4Y.DE       A4Y                       Accentro Real Estate AG  XETR   
10       A5G.I       A5G                                 AIB Group PLC  XDUB   
11      AAB.CO       AAB                      Aalborg Boldspilklub A/S  XCSE   
12      AAD.DE       AAD                               Amadeus Fire AG  XETR   
13      AAG.DE       AAG                                     Aumann AG  XETR   
14      AAK.ST       AAK                                        AAK AB  XSTO   
15     AALB.AS      AALB                        Aalberts Industries NV  XAMS   
16       AAL.L       AAL                            Anglo American PLC  XLON   
17      AAM.SW       AAM                            Anglo American PLC  XSWX   
18      AAQ.DE       AAQ                             AAP Implantate AG  XETR   
19       AAS.L       AAS              Aberdeen Standard Asia Focus PLC  XLON   
20        AA.L        AA                                        AA PLC  XLON   
21     ABBN.VX      ABBN                                       ABB Ltd  XVTX   
22      ABB.MC       ABB                                 AB-Biotics SA  XMAD   
23      ABB.ST       ABB                                       ABB Ltd  XSTO   
24     ABCA.PA      ABCA                                 ABC arbitrage  XPAR   
25     ABEO.PA      ABEO                                       Abeo SA  XPAR   
26       ABF.L       ABF                  Associated British Foods PLC  XLON   
27     ABGP.MC      ABGP                                    Abengoa SA  XMAD   
28      ABG.MC       ABG                                    Abengoa SA  XMAD   
29     ABIO.PA      ABIO                                    Albioma SA  XPAR   

   reuters_exchange_code  
0                    .DE  
1                    .DE  
2                    .DE  
3                     .L  
4                     .L  
5                    .DE  
6                    .DE  
7                    .MI  
8                    .MC  
9                    .DE  
10                    .I  
11                   .CO  
12                   .DE  
13                   .DE  
14                   .ST  
15                   .AS  
16                    .L  
17                   .SW  
18                   .DE  
19                    .L  
20                    .L  
21                   .VX  
22                   .MC  
23                   .ST  
24                   .PA  
25                   .PA  
26                    .L  
27                   .MC  
28                   .MC  
29                   .PA
```

Lets filter only the rows which have changed to show it worked:

```
print(df[(df['mic'] == 'XSWX') | (df['mic'] == 'XVTX')][['Symbol List', 'mic', 'reuters_exchange_code']])

   Symbol List   mic reuters_exchange_code
17      AAM.SW  XSWX                   .SW
21     ABBN.VX  XVTX                   .VX
```

Comment: woah this is it...thank you it worked! What a genoius =D

Comment: Pleasure, happy coding! @goaty

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you want:

```
#modify the code .S to SW for XSWX
df.loc[df['reuters_exchange_code'].eq('.S') & df['mic'].eq('XSWX'), 'reuters_exchange_code'] = 'SW'
#modify the code .S to VX for XVTX
df.loc[df['reuters_exchange_code'].eq('.S') & df['mic'].eq('XVTX'), 'reuters_exchange_code'] = 'VX'
:
:
#rebuild the symbol list
df['Symbol List'] = df['bats_name'] + df['reuters_exchange_code']
df = df.set_index('Symbol List')
```

Comment: Yes that is the idea but when I run your code I get an invalid syntax showing df['mic']

Comment: I have rerun your code but the output is the same as it was before...it is the right idea though